# How to evaluate SPeL expression in custom annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-expression-language, spring-expression

I'm using a custom annotation to execute some logic in an Aspect. I'd like my annotation to be able to evaluate a property in `application.yaml`. Here's what I have so far. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrect or point me in the right direction?

#### application.yaml

```yaml
app:
  name: my-application
```

#### MyAnno

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno {
  String name() default "";
}
```

#### ExampleService

```java
@Service
public class ExampleService {
  // stuff...

  @MyAnno(name = "${app.name}")
  public void someMethod(){
    // logic
  }
}
```

#### MyAspect

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(my.package.MyAnno)")
  public void annotatedMethods() {}

  @Around("annotatedMethods()")
  public Object doStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    MyAnno myAnno = method.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
    String evaluatedExpression = valueFromExpression(joinPoint, myAnno.name());
  }

  private String valueFromExpression(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String expression) {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    CodeSignature codeSignature = (CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    String[] parameterNames = codeSignature.getParameterNames();
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

    for (int i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
      context.setVariable(parameterNames[i], args[i]);
    }

    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);
    return exp.getValue(context, String.class);
  }
  
}
```

#### Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:135) ~[spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:52) ~[spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:43) ~[spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
```